# Python selenium webdriver. Find elements with specified class name

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium to parse a page containing markup that looks a bit like this:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Example</title></head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span class="Fw(500) D(ib) Fz(42px)">1</span>
            <span class="Fw(500) D(ib) Fz(42px) Green XYZ">2</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to fetch all span elements that contain the class foobar.

I have tried both of this (the variable wd is an instance of selenium.webdriver):

```
elem = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector("span[class='Fw(500) D(ib) Fz(42px).']")

elem = wd.find_element_by_xpath("//span[starts-with(@class, 'Fw(500) D(ib) Fz(42px))]")
```

NONE OF WHICH WORK.

How can I select only the elements that start with `Fw(500) D(ib) Fz(42px)`

i.e. both span elements in the sample markup given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below :-

```
elem = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.foobar")
```

If there is space between class `foo` and `bar` then try as below :-

```
elem = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.foo.bar")
```

**Edited** : If your class contains with non alphabetical charactor and you want to find element which starts with `Fw(500) D(ib) Fz(42px)` then try as below :-

```
elem = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector("span[class ^= 'Fw(500) D(ib) Fz(42px)']")
```

Comment: Sorry, I gave a bad example. My foobar actually contains spaces. I'll modify the question to reflect that

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli means `foo bar`??

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli ok then try updated answer with `elem = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.foo.bar")`

Comment: Sorry, my example was still wrong. I've corrected it and I'm using the actual class name now. Your code will not work, because my class name contains "non standard" characters - the page is generated by a React application.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Ok, now if you want to find element which element class start with `Fw(500) D(ib) Fz(42px)`...try updated answer..:)

Answer (score -1):

Try to find elements by XPath:

```
//span[@class='foobar']
```

This should work.

Comment: To be fair (to whomever marked this answer down). The question has since changed when this answer was given, and I have removed all references to foobar from my original question (see discussion with Saurabh Gaur below).